# Toujours vs encore to translate “still”?

Tags: choix-de-mot, indications-de-temps

I've always hesitated over this. What is the difference in usage between *encore* and *toujours* when translating the word *still*, in the sense of “I still hate olives.”?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"Still" can indeed be translated by either *encore* or *toujours* but,  depending on the context, both forms can have alternative meanings.

Instead of "still", *encore* might mean "again" while *toujours* might mean "always", e.g.:

- *Je suis encore là* = I'm still here **or** I'm here again
- *Je suis toujours là* = I'm still here **or** I'm always here
- *J'ai encore faim* = I'm still hungry **or** I'm hungry again
- *J'ai toujours faim* = I'm still hungry **or** I'm always hungry

There are cases where *encore* cannot be replaced by *toujours*. In such case, it can't be translated either by "still", e.g.:

- *J'ai encore crevé* = I had a flat tire again

Don't take that as a strict rule but to translate "still", you might prefer to use *encore* if the situation is more likely to change and use *toujours* if there is more continuity to expect.

Back to your example, if it is unlikely for your taste for olives to change, you would translate "I still hate olives." by:

- *Je déteste toujours les olives.*

but if there is some hope, that might be

- *Je déteste encore les olives*.

Answer (score 2):

> Instead of "still", *encore* might mean "again" while *toujours* might mean "always"

I agree for the essential but I would like to add yet other meanings.

- *encore* might also mean something like "more"; e.g. *encore mieux* -> "even better", *encore plus* -> even further
  (note that I didn't say that *encore* means "even" though: in those expressions its fundamental sense is closer to "more")
- *toujours* might also sometimes stand for "already", like in *c'est toujours ça de pris* (which is equivalent to *c'est déjà ça de pris*); I'm not pretty sure of how it might be said in English, but Google gives me "it's still better than nothing", respectively "it's already better than nothing"

Answer (score 0):

*encore* it's for something which have been appear in the past and re-appear an other time. it's an action at this time

*toujours* is in the continuous ... it have been always like that

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack-Exchange ! Please be more precise while answering such a question, because it seems very confusing here. You may add exemples (as jlliagre did), clarify what is the real difference (as milk2go did), or make a longer answer to understand your point of view. Thanks.