# When “toujours” appears, how do I know if it means “always” instead of “still”?

Tags: indications-de-temps, adverbes

There are posts like the following [Toujours vs encore to translate “still”?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/16707/toujours-vs-encore-to-translate-still) that state that *still* can be translated with both toujours and encore.

**Please note that my question is different. I am not asking about which of the words *toujours* or *encore* to use to translate the word *still*.** I understand that there is a post that talks about how *still* can be translated by two different words, but that is not my question.

---

I want to know, if I see the word *toujours*, how do I know if it means "always" instead "still", or vice versa.

For example, suppose I have a friend Chris whom my housemate was once friends with but now dislikes. In English, my housemate might say "I still hate it when Chris visits you" (that is, emphasizing that he still has not forgiven Chris despite the passage of time), or "I always hate it when Chris visits you" (that is, emphasizing his annoyance with my habitual decision to invite Chris despite me knowing that he doesn't like him).

But in French, if my housemate said to me, "Je déteste toujours quand Chris vient te voir", I am not sure which meaning my housemate intends. I want to know which meaning is communicated when my housemate says this French sentence, and what are the rules about which meaning is communicated when the context does not make this clear.

---

Edit: Another example.

(Although, this is a different but very similar question).

There is a story from today's (January 7th) edition of a French newspaper (called Le Journal De Québec) that I was reading in a bar tonight. Here is the headline and the first few sentences (ie, to provide context) :

> La tension monte entre Uber et les taxis.
> Le président de Taxi Coop prédit des "réchauffements" après l'agression alléguée dún chauffeur de l'entreprise.
>
> La tension monte **encore** d'un cran entre Uber et les compagnies de taxi, alors qu'un chauffeur de Taxi Coope avance avoir été menacé avec une arme de type Taser, mardi: un événement qui laisse présager plusiers "réchauffements", selon Abdallah Homsy, président de Taxi Coop.

Google Translate translates the sentence in question with "still", as in "The tension rises still a notch between Uber and Taxi Companies". However, I cannot tell by context whether this is "Tension mounts still" (Tension continues to mount), or "Tension mounts again", and this is an important difference for a newspaper article to make.

Note: I had read carefully the "Toujours vs encoure to translate "still"?" post before adding this edit, but I could not find any clues about this question, there.

Comment: http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/16707/toujours-vs-encore-to-translate-still

Comment: In real life conversation, it is very unlikely for the context not to make clear what meaning *toujours* has. Should for some reason you are unsure, there is no rule, just ask for clarification.

Comment: @jiliagre: It seems that I won't be convinced until I use French more in real life and see that this is true. Thanks for this clear, direct response to my question.

Comment: I see no significant difference between both of your translations. The fact that is reported by the newspaper is the tension is higher that it was previously.

Comment: @jlliagre, isn't there a difference of "still" implying that the tensions have been continuously strong over the past (say) few days, and "again" implying that the tensions were not so strong during the past few days but then have flared up again just now?

Comment: If the tension *monte encore*, that clearly means it stayed high, otherwise that would have been *la tension remonte*.

Comment: Est-ce qu'il n'existe pas une réponse qui y répond, ta question ? Cela ne me dérangerait  pas, si j'ai tort, mais plein de personnes ont pris du temps  pour t'aider.

Comment: @MasonH.Hatfield, there hasn't been an answer below that answers the question I had, but it's probably because I need to ask the question more precisely. I'm going to select an answer below as the "accepted answer", just so that the work people did in responding doesn't get lost forever.

Comment: I agree with you this is very confusing. For example, if I saw someone in a coffee shop and later saw him there again, saying "Il était toujours là" can mean either "he's still there" or "he's always there".

Comment: Another example: In L’Étranger, Meursault asks his neighbour why he curses his dog, to which he answers « Il est toujours là. » In some translation this is translated as "He is still here" and in some to "He's always there".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**

I just saw your updated question and from what I have heard, learned, and experienced it seems to be that most people use *encore* just to avoid the confusion. I do not believe that in an authentic conversation that clarity would be needed for as to the the meaning of *toujours*, nor do I believe there is a rule, or guideline as to deciphering the meaning. Simply ask for clarification.

**Something along the lines:**

> Veuillez préciser ce que tu viens de me dire.
>   (Please clarify what you just told me)

---

Still can be translated by *Encore* and *Toujours* (In some cases *néanmoins*, or nonetheless)

> Néanmoins je crois qu'il te faut changer tes réponses! (Still I believe you must change your answers!)

If 'still' modifies an adjective, then you should use '*encore*'.

> Bien qu'il soit plus agé que moi, il est encore plus vite.

In the case like: They're still hungry!

'*Toujours*' should be used in that example.

> Ils ont toujours faim.

Other examples:

> Malgré le fait que je t'aie vu dans mes rêves, je suis encore ravi de faire ta connaisance. (Despite the fact that I've seen you in my dreams, I am still delighted to meet you.)

**or**

> I'm always/still here = je suis toujours là (Lorsque t'as besoin de moi, également pour raconter qu'on n'a pas bougé )

See [here](http://french.about.com/library/weekly/aa021601et.htm).

Please see [this](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/16707/toujours-vs-encore-to-translate-still) for more specific explanation.

Comment: my question is: if I see "toujours" in a sentence, how do I know if it means "still", vs if it means "always"? For example, "Ils ont toujours faim", how do you know it means "They are still hungry" instead of "They are always hungry"?

Comment: Only the context will tell you in some cases like that one.

Comment: I'm a little suspicious about the idea that context is always enough to help me tell the difference! I'll let others answer, but if no one gives more clarity I'll assume that you're fully right, jiliagre, and that some sentences with _toujours_ are ambiguous without context.

Comment: The context of the environment in which the conversation takes place should make sense.  For example ask yourself: Does 'still' fit in the context of the conversation? You could always try using synonyms of 'still'. [link](http://www.wordreference.com/enfr/even%20now) like 'Even Now', 'Up until now', etc.

Comment: @MasonH.Hatfield May I give you an example where I would still be confused? For example, suppose I had my friend Chris over, and the next day my housemate (who used to be friends with Chris but now hates him) tells me "Je detest toujours quand Chris te va voir". I can't tell if this means "I always hate when Chris visits you", or "I still hate when Chris visits you". Is it really true that context always clears which meaning is intended? It's hard for me to believe!

Comment: "Je detest toujours quand Chris te va voir" is not correct French. She would say something like "Je déteste que Chris vienne te voir" or perhaps "Je déteste quand Chris vient te voir".

Comment: @jiliagre, thanks for that correction. I was using Google Translate, which translated "to visit someone" as "aller voir". I updated the edit to my original post to use your correction.

Comment: @jlliagre Yes, that was incorrect. I was a bit puzzled at first until I read your correction. Anyways, sorry I just saw your comment.  Yes to your main question as well. There are some cases where it can't be translated by 'encore'. It could mean either 'Still' or 'Always' as well. It's just a matter of the conversation topic as well. For example: If you've hated Chris for 5 years, then which would make more sense? Although either could replace it. (I am talking to Jlliagre and the post owner to be clear)

Comment: *Je déteste toujours quand Chris vient te voir* is still not idiomatic. Neither *encore* nor *toujours* would probably be used by French native speakers here. In any case, the context makes it clear your housemate hates these visits and is unlikely to change her mind, regardless of whether *toujours* or *encore* are there or not.

Comment: @jlliagre I am aware, I was just telling the OP that s/he needs to look at the context of the conversation as well.

Comment: You're right, I will update the question until the OP chooses, although I've not seen much activity from him lately.

Comment: @Legomononc'bléd'Ingres I did not ask, because I was angry, just out of my earnest desire to improve my answers, i appreciate the critique! i also added more examples.

Comment: @MasonH.Hatfield, I appreciate you directly telling me, as jiliagre had done, that you believe that context will usually make the meaning of _toujours_ clear, and that there is no rule when the meaning isn't clear. If I come across, or think of, more sentences where the meaning is unclear, I might collect them and then at some future time make a new question presenting these sentences. Thanks for your update to your answer. (Or, maybe I'll get real wisdom from Legomononc's answer once I understand it!)

Comment: So, instead of collecting sentences over time and then later posting them on a future date, I had found one example in a newspaper just half an hour ago, on my last day of vacation here in Québec city, and have just now editted my question with another example, although this time about "encore" instead of "toujours".

Answer (score 2):

*Le bon usage* (Grevisse et Goosse, ed. Duculot, 14<sup>e</sup>, §1006, 957) dit, en bref, que *toujours* c'est principalement la *permanence* par continuité ou répétition et qu'on manie la durée à l'aide de l'ajout d'une préposition (*pour, à; depuis*). Deuxièmement, toujours peut indiquer la *persistance* jusqu'au moment du temps du verbe et vaut *encore* dans ce contexte (« Et bien, petite, est-on toujours fâchée ? » (Maupassant) ; « Il ne comprenait toujours pas le succès du *Bonheur des Dames* » (Zola, *Bonheur des Dames*). Troisièmement *toujours* peut perdre sa valeur de temps pour signifier *en tout cas/en attendant*. On note aussi que dans certaines régions on utilise *encore* pour *déjà* en explétif dans la langue parlée. On dit toujours plein d'autres choses partout. Enfin on rappelle souvent comment le ***contexte*** est déterminant ; il va sans dire (voir aussi [ceci](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/16707) pour certains défis de traduction).

---

[ *Toujours* is mainly about *permanence* (continuous or through repetition); the time frame can be tuned with a preposition (*pour, à, depuis + toujours*). It can also be about *persistence*, up to the moment referred to with the verb tense; it means *encore*. Finally *toujours* could mean something unrelated to duration: *in any case* etc. Context is central. ]

---

Sur ces entrefaites, le français n'est pas une [traduction](https://translate.google.com/#auto/fr/I%20still%20hate%20it%20when%20Chris%20visits%20you.) de l'anglais. La phrase qu'on présente est calquée et me semble personnellement incomplète (*hate **it*** ; il y a un pronom), et je ne peux m'imaginer l'entendre en [effet](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/17162/when-toujours-appears-how-do-i-know-if-it-means-always-instead-of-still#comment32348_17163) avec l'un ou l'autre des adverbes dans cette [position](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/17162/when-toujours-appears-how-do-i-know-if-it-means-always-instead-of-still#comment32315_17163). Je présente ce qui me vient à l'esprit en réfléchissant à la question. Dans mon sociolecte (en *français québécois*) :

> — Je déteste ça (cela) quand Chris vient te voir : je lui en veux
>   toujours/encore... [avec pronom]
>  
>   — J'haïs (ça) voir Chris : il dit toujours des bêtises... [toutes les fois, systématiquement] 
>   — Même aujourd'hui, je déteste (toujours/encore) ça quand Chris... [alors que normalement]
>  — ..., j'haïs ça/je n'aime pas que
>   Chris vienne te voir... [en soi ; *aime pas*, par euphémisme]
>   — Ça m'ennuie que Chris vienne encore et toujours te voir. [la persistance, la fréquence]
>   — Je te déteste d'inviter/quand tu invites Chris ! Tu sais pourquoi... [détestations multiples !]
>    — J[e n]'aime toujours
>   pas (ça) quand [ce] Chris[-là] vient/que [ce] Chris[-là] vienne [ici pour] te voir... [un autre calque (?) ; et avec jeu de mot sur le juron difficile à éviter ici...]

On peut imaginer différentes combinaisons. J'ai le réflexe d'ajouter le pronom *ça* quand *détester* n'est pas directement construit comme un des [trois cas](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/d%C3%A9tester/24816/difficulte) mentionné au *Larousse* (+ nom, + inf., + que). Je ne sais pas si je sens vraiment une nuance entre détester Chris, détester qu'il vienne parce que je le déteste depuis un moment antérieur et détester sa visite; du premier au deuxième au troisième. Quoiqu'il en soit, le calque (de *still/always hate it*) n'est pas requis pour faire un sous-entendu à mon avis alors que *même aujourd'hui (encore)* ou une variante le permet (un renforcement pour rappeler inversement la valeur normale - *ne pas* détester en contexte etc.). Évidemment, rien de ceci n'est exhaustif.

---

[ The provided sentence is generated with a translation tool and feels off to me, in part because it uses a construction where you neither have a name, an infinitive nor a construction introduced with *que* yet there is no pronoun following the verb (that *it* in *hate it*). To create an implication about a past event, I didn't need to use *toujours* after the verb like you did. Rather, I've found that beginning the sentence with *même aujourd'hui (encore)* i.e. *even to (this) day (still)* feels more natural to me (Québec French here); it underscores how unusual hating on *this day* feels to sort of hint about what might have happened in the past. Some examples explore shifting the blame (*I hate you for having him over*) and stereotyping the visitor (*that goddamn Chris*) as means of implying something about prior events. Other examples leverage other verbs (*haïr, ennuyer*), and euphemism (*I don't like it when*) etc. ]

Comment: Une petite remarque pour les non francophones: *J'haïs* \ʒa.i\ est du français québécois. Ailleurs, on dit *Je hais* \ʒə ɛ\ , sometimes \ʒə e\.

Comment: The *tréma* in *j'haïs* keeps its sound more-or-less distinct from *j'ai*.

Comment: Is it okay if I try to translate this answer (over the next few days) and post it here, so that people can then correct any errors concerning ways I misunderstood the content of this post? (Google Translate seems to be doing a poor job at translating this answer!)

Comment: I can only agree with the first part. The  second part is interesting, but still foreign to me ;-)

Comment: @Legomononc'bléd'Ingres Actually, the whole thing is not clear to me because my French is so poor that it would take me about half an an hour (or maybe more?) and lots of Google Translate (for individual words and phrases) for me to (attempt to) translate this into English! I hope to see the points you made here after translating your response.

Answer (score 0):

For your first example : "Je déteste toujours quand Chris vient te voir"
With this sentence order, it has to be "still". If you would like to have the meaning with "always", the sentence would be different. French language is more direct so it'll looks like "Je déteste que tu invites Chris"

For your second example, it depends of context. At the moment, tensions already exist and for a long time, so it is translated by "still".
To have "again" instead of "still", you need to have another sentence. Something like "The Uber driver who was been hitten last month has been strokken again."

Answer (score 0):

Je pense que Toujours signifie 'always', n'importe l'usage; ainsi 'encore' represent le 'yet' ou 'and yet', 'still' ....alors, encore tu persiste en m'resistant! Montagnards!